# SQL impasse ao modelar

Tags: sql, algoritmo, modelagem

Tenho a seguinte condição:

1. num_serie: uma sequencia única de 20 caracteres que representa a identificação de batismo do produto, sempre existirá.
2. ns1,ns2,ns3,ns4: uma sequencia numérica de 6 dígitos, onde algum ou todos podem ser vazios. Também são únicos e essas variáveis nunca devem ser iguais entre elas, tanto na linha quanto na tabela.

Modelei o banco como abaixo:

```
   CREATE TABLE `produto` (
 `id_produto` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `num_serie` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `modelo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `ns1` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ns2` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ns3` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ns4` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_produto`,`num_serie`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Dúvida: Existe alguma forma de atribuir a ns1,ns2,ns3 e ns4 como PRIMARY KEY e simultaneamente poderem ser nulos ?
Enfim, posso resolver esse impasse com SQL (outra tabela e comandos SQL) ou terei que resolver o critério de permissão de INSERÇÃO por algoritmo?

Comment: Por que quer que sejam PK? Não bastaria uma chave UNIQUE?

Comment: Existem problemas que só existem pois foram criados , normalize a tabela , (id_produto,num_serie,ns,seqns) , não existindo não crie (caso do null) e use uma trigger ou procedure para limitar aos 4 casos. Para o caso de precisar pivotear existem soluções comforme o Banco (não informado) , talvez exista uma solução para tratar este modelo mais creio que seria complicada.

Comment: Nota , o ns pode ser além pode ser uma unique key também.

Answer (score -1):

Incompleta ainda , basicamente normalizar a tabela citada.

```
CREATE TABLE `produto` (
  `id_produto` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num_serie` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `modelo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_produto`, `num_serie`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4


CREATE TABLE `produto_ns` (
  `id_produto` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num_serie` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `seq` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `ns` int(6) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT UK_SERIAL UNIQUE (ns),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_produto`, `num_serie`,`seq`,`ns`)  
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4


ALTER TABLE `produto_ns`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_produto`, `num_serie`) REFERENCES `produto`(`id_produto`, `num_serie`);
```

Falta tratar a restrição de 4 "ns"s por produto ,
poderia ser tratado por trigger ou procedure.

Mas concordo com a negativação , resposta incompleta.

Answer (score -2):

Formatei as tabelas, não sei bem a diferença entre 2 modelos. Estão corretos?

```
CREATE TABLE `produto` (
  `id_produto` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num_serie` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `modelo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ns1` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ns2` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ns3` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ns4` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT UK_SERIAL UNIQUE (ns1, ns2, ns3, ns4),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_produto`, `num_serie`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4

CREATE TABLE `produto` (
  `id_produto` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num_serie` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `modelo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ns1` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ns2` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ns3` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ns4` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_produto`,`num_serie`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_SERIAL` (`ns1`,`ns2`,`ns3`,`ns4`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Pega o conteúdo dessa resposta e adiciona lá na pergunta, depois remove a resposta. Tenta explicar melhor o que é ns1, ns2, ns3 e ns4, só a descrição do formato do campo não está ajudando muito, pois poderia ser número de série, que já está sendo usado em outro campo, aparentemente são informações que deveriam ficar em outra tabela e não na produto.

Answer (score -3):

Chaves primárias devem possui valores únicos. Aconselho a adicionar uma variável (id) que seja auto incrementada. Se não, crie outra tabela de forma a construir um relacionamento.